# Syntax: yield return enumerable without loop

Tags: c#, syntax

Is it possible?

```
List<Cat> _Cats; // created somewhere else

public IEnumerable<Cat> LeadWithLolCat()
{
    yield return RandomLolCat();

    // can we return all the other cats without creating a loop?
    foreach ( var cat in _Cats ) // -> so not like this
        yield return cat;
}
```

Comment: No this isn't possible.

Comment: I think you're confused about the usage of `yield` keyword. Elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange - He wants something like `yield!` in F# list/sequence comprehensions e.g. `seq { yield RandomLolCat(); yield! _Cats }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `Concat` like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Cat> LeadWithLolCat()
{
    return new [] { RandomLolCat() }.Concat(_Cats);
}
```

Comment: This works well for this particular example, but does not provide an answer for the general case (and that answer is: *it's not possible*).

Answer (score -3):

To directly answer the asked question, I don't believe it is possible to achieve what seems to be your intended result given your syntax.

It sounds like what you would want is to return the known `List<Cat>` with the `RandomLolCat` prepended. Why not just do it without the `yield` keyword?

```
List<Cat> _Cats; // created somewhere else

public IEnumerable<Cat> LeadWithLolCat()
{
    var result = _Cats.Select(e=> e);
    result.Insert(new RandomLolCat(), 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1) what is the point of `_Cats.Select(e=> e)`? 2) `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have an Insert method. 3) `RandomLolCat` is not a class it's a method.